# Unknown column in field list

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting the error `Unknown Column in field List`.

The database has these fields:

```
ID - AUTO INCRIMENT
username
password
groupID
prefs_list_item
```

Here is my code. The variables are stored above as a set value which I know isn't giving me any issue, because I use them in other databases in the same script.

```
try {
$wpdb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=******', '*******', 
'*******');
$wpdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Creates the SQL statement to write into the picture database
$pictureUPDATE = $wpdb->prepare
("INSERT INTO pe_users (
username,
password,
groupID
) VALUES (
$username,
$passmd5,
$groupID
)
");
//Executes the writing into the picture database
$pictureUPDATE->execute();
echo("<p>Your account to upload photos is now active!</p>");            
                                        }
//catches any errors that might have come from updating the picture databse
catch (PDOException $ex) {
       $msg = $ex->errorInfo;
       error_log(var_export($msg, true));
       die("<p>Sorry, there was a unrecoverable database error with PICTURES.  
       Debug data has been logged.</p>");
                         }
```

Not sure what's going on, anyone have a clue?

Comment: MD5 is not secure.  You should use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: You are calling `prepare()` but you have not bound any variables. Instead, you have simply inserted the PHP variables `$username, $passmd5, $groupID`. You are getting none of the security of the prepared statement. (not to mention that your variables appear not to be quoted, unless they are quoted in the string variables themselves)

Comment: But are you certain it is that `INSERT` statement causing the error?

Comment: @SLaks Unforentally for the picture gallery that is installed I need to use MD5 since thats how it was made.  I know it loses all the safety of the PDO but I am calling these varibles from another database so there is no chance of injection so I feel rather safe using it this way

Comment: Is your table created in the database as described above? you may have it created but with a missing column, at the time of running the insert.

Comment: yes its exactly like stated above.

Comment: `groupID` seems to be the problem.As group is a reserved word in SQL try changing it to `grpID`

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
$data = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $passmd5, 'groupID' => $groupID );

$pictureUPDATE = $wpdb->("INSERT INTO pe_users 
          (username, password, groupID) value (:username, :password, :groupID)");

$pictureUPDATE->execute($data);
```

Comment: Nope same issue:

    `[28-Nov-2012 21:53:46] array (

      0 => '42S22',

      1 => 1054,

      2 => 'Unknown column \'****\' in \'field list\'',

    )`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `groupID` wasnt the issue, around my varibles I needed to add `'{ }'` so it looked like this....
    `$pictureUPDATE = $wpdb->prepare
    ("INSERT INTO pe_users (
    username,
    password,
    groupID
    ) VALUES (
    '{$username}',
    '{$passmd5}',
    '{$groupID}'
    )
    ");`